# How to start Genymotion device with shell command?

Tags: android, shell, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I need to start genymotion via shell command, does anyone know if it is possible to do this?

Comment: Quick link to Genymotion FAQ is https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=start-virtual-devices-command-prompt#faq

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Genymotion proposes a shell: the [Genymotion Shell](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#collapse9). It is not currently possible to start a VM with it.

But you can however launch a Genymotion VM thanks to this command:

`player --vm-name <VM id | VM name>`

This command launches the Genymotion's player that gives you access to all the Genymotion enhancements widgets (GPS, battery, rotation, ...), the screen scaling, rendering, ... Like the standard GUI launch.

If you want to use a Genymotion VM without the enhancements, you can launch it via the VirtualBox command line like this:

`VBoxManage startvm gui <VM id | VM name>`

The VM id can be found thanks to this command line:

`VBoxManage list vms`

It displays a list of your VirtualBox machines on this format: `name {id}`.

**UPDATE**

Since Genymotion 2.5.0 you can manage all your Genymotion devices thanks to a command line tool. With this tool you can create, start, stop, delete, push files, flash the device, ...
Here is a simple example to create a device and start it:

```
gmtool admin create "Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920" myNexus
gmtool admin start myNexus
```

This feature is available for paid licenses.

Comment: Check the update. I've given you the right command line to launch the VM as it is on the GUI.

Comment: I use Genymotion on a Mac. I can't find "player" command. How do I find it?

Comment: Your prompt need to be located on the Genymotion folder where the "player" binary is. I don't know where it should be on a Mac.

Comment: Ok, solved it. It turned out that I was able to start Genymotion only as root. So the VM was in the VirtualBox for the root account... Sorry.

Comment: @David find it inside the application bundle

Comment: player was located at /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player on Mac.

Comment: This help me start a Genymotion VM from shell, but is there any way to run the VM headless totally? I mean no GUI when running the virtual device, like Android's `emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window`?

Comment: This is not supported for the moment by Genymotion.

Comment: When I use `VBoxManage startvm gui <vm>`, I get a shell, but the OS doesn't enter a graphical mode. Works fine when Genymotion starts the VM. What's Genymotion doing differently?

Comment: Hi Daniel, the Genymotion player that you launch with `player --vm-name` opens a channel with the VM to handle the Android graphical stack rendering. By this we are able to render all the graphics through the computer's GPU.

Comment: The `player --vm-name` stuff is very neat. I added it as a shortcut to the Windows taskbar. Very seamless experience! Thank you!

Comment: @xialin to stop the emulator simply run the same command with -x at the end

Answer (score 22):

For windows.

Retrieve the list of available virtual devices by running:

```
<Genymotion installer path>\genyshell -c "devices list"
```

Start one of the virtual devices by running:

```
<Genymotion installer path>\player --vm-name "<virtual device name>"
```

**UPD 8 may 2019:**
I'm create simple wrapper for genymotion cli on bash. Link to github [here](https://github.com/yshinkarev/my-bash/blob/master/android/genymotion_tools.sh).

Comment: It works for Linux also (well, you have to change the slashes of course)

Comment: As of today, this is the only way to run a device via command line without paying for a license. +1

Comment: To halt VM: `player -n $NAME -x`

Comment: The github link is broken

Comment: Fixed, correct link is https://github.com/yshinkarev/my-bash/blob/master/android/genymotion_tools.sh

Answer (score 20):

As of Genymotion 2.6.0 (Dec 2015), it appears they have moved the `player` executable to be `player.app`.

On OSX you can launch a desired VM like this:

```
# First, get a list of the VM's you have installed
VBoxManage list vms
# Returns something like "5.0.0 - API 21 - 768x1280" {091d022d-6a7b-4475-845f-7a6e06024fb6}
```

Copy the VM ID, e.g. `091d022d-6a7b-4475-845f-7a6e06024fb6`, and then use it again like this:

```
# Launch a specific VM
open -a /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app --args --vm-name '091d022d-6a7b-4475-845f-7a6e06024fb6'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @eyal-lezmy answer, here is what I do with the current Genymotion 3.2.1:

- List the available devices

```
gmtool admin list
```

*Output example*

```
 State    |   ADB Serial    |                UUID                |      Name
----------+-----------------+------------------------------------+---------------
      Off |         0.0.0.0 |6aa30cf2-217a-4a27-9d29-13e41a351bd7| Google Pixel 3
      Off |         0.0.0.0 |8ab62c9c-ef26-4a6b-870c-8db4fa54ed76| Samsung Galaxy S9
```

- Start a device

```
player -n 8ab62c9c-ef26-4a6b-870c-8db4fa54ed76
```

Instructions to find the binary location can be found in the [Genymotion Shell doc](https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/05_Genymotion_Shell/)