# Genymotion startup commands

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

I'm new to genymotion.  How do I send startup commands to the emulator?  I would like it to startup up with out the "Android" graphic and to scale the screen to a smaller size.  I know how to do this with the google android emulator, but am unsure with genymotion.  Any ideas are appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the emulator in command line. All the information are available on [this other StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768489/how-to-start-genymotion-device-with-shell-command/18773118#18773118)

Concerning the screen scaling, this is not currently possible through Genymotion tools. You can maybe find other tools for your specific host platform.