# how to create desktop shortcut for android device in genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

You mentitoned here:

[How to start Genymotion device with shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768489/how-to-start-genymotion-device-with-shell-command/24992650#24992650)

I just could not figure what am I missing.

My shortcut is

```
"C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\player.exe" --House <id | House>
```

I have tried different symbols and syntaxes but the shortcut doesn't start anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Genymotion here but based on the question you linked to the syntax should be something like

```
"C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\player.exe" --vm-name House
```

where `House` is the id or name of your VM.

Comment: nope nothing happens could it be because of the location of the depolyed device as there is the folder House under C:\Users\House\VirtualBox VMs

Answer (score 1):

> I read the documentation for Genymotion shell and came up with the following solution. I hope it helps someone

**Create a batch file**

Open your favorite text editor and save the following text has [filename].bat

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
start player --vm-name "marshmello"
exit
```

> Here marshmello is the name of my virtual device  You will surely need
>   to replace with your own

**Create a new shortcut**

The easiest way to do is

1. Right Click on your desktop
2. Select shortcut inside new option
3. put the path of the [filename].bat file you just created in it.

Now, You can open your virtual device with a single shortcut :)

> If you want to open multiple devices just add more of these

```
start player --vm-name "[your-device-name]"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Genymotion plugin for Android Studio to manage it's virtual devices (create and start)

Answer (score 0):

The content of my `*.cmd` file:

```
start "C:\Program Files\Genymotion" "C:\Program Files\Genymotion\player.exe" --vm-name="Google Nexus 5"
```

"Google Nexus 5" you need to replace it with your virtual device name in quotes

it works for me