# Is it possible to save and re-use device state from Gennymotion Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I need few emulators with the same setup.

I have created my emulator, configured it (used memory, processors, space etc.), after that I have installed GooglePlayServices and created account for it.

I need 4 the same emulators, additionally I will need them on other PCs.

Is it possible to avoid process of recreating each of those from scratch?
Can I save image of my emulator or at least state of android device with configured GooglePlayServices in some way and re-use it?

Comment: Gennymotion use virtualbox for image, Goto your virtual box settings and copy the image.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

method 1: clone device, see [clone](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/03_Virtual_Devices/Managing_virtual_devices/Cloning_a_virtual_device.htm)

method 2: copy the virtual device files from path **\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Genymobile** see [copy virtual device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547965/5241603)

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answer. 
I have still problem. Clone won't work because I don't have PRO-User. When I copy folder .Genymotion with my devices to some location, then delete .Genymotion folder that is used by Genymotion app - in result Emulator List is clean. When I copy .Genymotion back then Emulator List has all my devices and settings restored.

It works on PC on which I have created Emulators. When I try to copy my .Genymotion folder to other PC I can't see any emulators in list.