# How to copy virtual devices downloaded by Genymotion to another machine in MAC OS?

Tags: android, macos, virtualbox, genymotion

I am having same question described in link but with MAC the version is described below..

[How to copy virtual devices downloaded by Genymotion to another machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17538686/7118826)

Mac OS X El Capitan v10.11.12.

Genymotion version 2.7.2

Thanks is advance.